# Genexus Repository connection failed for user XXX (GAM32)

Tags: connection, repository, credentials, genexus

I'm new on Stack Overflow so greetings to all.

I have a problem on GAM of some Genexus Projects (G16 U4-5-6-7… we have tried with different upgrade).

When I compile the project this error appears:
Repository connection failed for user XXX. Please contact the application administrator. (GAM32)

We have tried to solve following the workaround described on SAC:
Work Arround (Spanish only)
Definir el usuario de conexión a la Base de Datos en texto claro dentro del archivo connection.gam.

But the problem still exists!! (We have tried to use different username and password… admin, gamadmin, database credentials… but in this case what kind of credentials are needed?).

We have also tried to generate the connection.gam with the deployment toolkit.

How can we solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Administrator User Name Property, Administrator User Password Property, Connection User Name Property, or Connection User Password Property properties?

Further information about the error and action to be taken: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22815,GAM%20Troubleshooting#1.+GAM%28%29%3A+Repository+connection+failed+for+user.

I hope it help you
Gustavo